# How to delete data from multiple tables in one query

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, like so:

```
release (release_id, name, ...)

medium (medium_id, release_id, name, ...)

track (track_id, medium_id, title, ...)
```

Having only the release_id, i want to be able delete both the track and the medium associated with that release_id in one shot using one query.

Is it possible? If yes, can I get a rough template, I'll figure out the rest.

Do I need multiple delete queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this in one statement by referencing multiple tables in the delete statement:

```
DELETE FROM `release`, medium, track
USING `release`, medium, track
WHERE `release`.release_id = medium.release_id 
AND medium.medium_id = track.medium_id
AND `release`.release_id = 1;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f68a6/1)

If this is something that should always happen you might want to have a look at the `on delete cascade` option for foreign keys. See the docs for more information: [13.1.14.2 Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, yes, you need three separate delete statements.

However, if you always want the associated rows deleted from the other two tables when you delete a row from the 'release' table, you can use foreign keys and an ON DELETE CASCADE constraint on the 'release' table.

See, e.g. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Answer (score 1):

In the first line you define from which tables you want to delete in the join

```
delete r, m, t
from release r
left join medium m on m.release_id = r.release_id
left join track t on t.medium_id = m.medium_id
where r.release_id = 123
```